# Crossbrowser Javascript Listener

Tags: javascript, listener

I have the next code working correctly:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('register');
for(var index = 0; index < links.length; ++index)
{
   links[index].addEventListener('click', function(){
       var newMixpanelEvent = 'mixpanel.track("Click On Searched List", {"user is logged": "no"})';
       trackEvent(newMixpanelEvent);
       });
}
```

This is just listening for a click event, and then executing a function to create an event to Mixpanel.

Now I need to check the `addEventListener` function and `attachEvent` to make it work almost all browsers, so I do:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('register');
for(var index = 0; index < links.length; ++index)
{
   if( links[index].addEventListener ) {
       links[index].addEventListener('click', function(){
           var newMixpanelEvent = 'mixpanel.track("Click On Searched List", {"user is logged": "no"})';
           trackEvent(newMixpanelEvent);
           });        
   } else if( links[index].attachEvent ) {
       links[index].attachEvent('onclick', function(){
           var newMixpanelEvent = 'mixpanel.track("Click On Searched List", {"user is logged": "no"})';
           trackEvent(newMixpanelEvent);
           });
   }
}
```

But this is not firing the events. Seems like `if( links[index].addEventListener )` is not passing. Any idea of why?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: @TanzeelKazi - No errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the above code works right. The problem was that I had not cleared cache. This is what I previously had and didn't work:

```
if( window.addEventListener ) { 
    ...
```

But

```
if( links[index].addEventListener ) {
    ...
```

is working right.

Answer (score 0):

As a final fallback you can add the event through onclick attribute. You should define sperate function with the logic for checking available ways for attaching event handlers.

```
function addCrossBrowserEvent(element, eventName, callback){
    if(element.addEventListener){
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback);
    }
    else if(element.attachEvent){
        element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, callback);
    }
    else{
        element['on' + eventName] = callback;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
addCrossBrowserEvent(myElement, 'click', function() { 
    alert('clicked'); 
});
```

Note: Also you can try to design it as extension of HTMLElement prototype.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.addCrossBrowserEvent = function(eventName, callback) {
    if(this.addEventListener){
        this.addEventListener(eventName, callback);
    }
    else if(this.attachEvent){
        this.attachEvent('on' + eventName, callback);
    }
    else{
        this['on' + eventName] = callback;
    }
}

// Usage
document.getElementById('elementId').addCrossBrowserEvent('click', function() { 
    // ... 
});
```